# Objective-C - Search for streets based on user-entered query

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cllocation, mklocalsearch

I want to allow the users to search for a street name and have the results displayed in a UITableView. 
For the moment the region is not important, it can be from any region.

I could not find any relevant example in my searches and I don't know if I should use CLLocation or MKLocalSearch.

Based on docs, I should use MKLocalSearch:

> Although local search and geocoding are similar, they support
>   different use cases. Use geocoding when you want to convert between
>   map coordinates and a structured address, such as an Address Book
>   address. Use local search when you want to find a set of locations
>   that match the user’s input.

But I have tried both methods and it gives me only 1 result (even-though there is an NSArray returned.

This is the CLGeocoder approach:

```
CLGeocoder *geocoding = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoding geocodeAddressString:theTextField.text completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%i", [placemarks count]);
        for(CLPlacemark *myStr in placemarks) {
            NSLog(@"%@", myStr);
    }
    }
}];
```

And this is my MKLocalSearch try:

```
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = theTextField.text;
request.region = self.region;

localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error){

    if (error != nil) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Map Error",nil)
                                    message:[error localizedDescription]
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",nil) otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        return;
    }

    if ([response.mapItems count] == 0) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"No Results",nil)
                                    message:nil
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",nil) otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        return;
    }
    self.streets = response;
    [self.streetsTableView reloadData];
}];
```

MKLocalSearch seems to return more than 1 response in some cases, but these are related to places not street names searches.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try setting region to nil? or can you share more details on your self.region?

Comment: I have a MapView and I am using MapView.region as self.region

Comment: from my experience MKLocalSearch is very primitive. Would you be opposed to using Google Places API for any reason?

Comment: google has a [more useful api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), MKLocalSearch is for a simple tasks only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the closest I could get. This involves using [google places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/intro).  
**Note:** You could probably use their Google Maps API, etc. I am sure there are other ways to get this information from the various Google APIs.

```
 NSURL *googlePlacesURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=%@&location=%f,%f&sensor=true&key=API_KEY", formattedSearchText, location.coordinate.latitude,
                                                   location.coordinate.longitude]];
```

The response is a JSON object. Convert it to a dictionary.

```
 NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_googlePlacesResponse
                                                                    options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

if([[response objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"OK"])
{
    NSArray *predictions = [response objectForKey:@"predictions"];
    for(NSDictionary *prediction in predictions)
    {
        NSArray *addressTypes = [prediction objectForKey:@"types"];
        if([addressTypes containsObject:@"route"])
        {
            //This search result contains a street name. 
            //Now get the street name.
            NSArray *terms = [prediction objectForKey:@"terms"];
            NSDictionary *streetNameKeyValuePair = [terms objectAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"%@",[streetNameKeyValuePair objectForKey@"value"]);
        }
    }
}
```

The possible `types` seem to be

Route -> Street name

Locality -> City/location name

Political -> State, etc

Geocode -> lat/long available

You could populate the table view with those `predictions` that **ONLY** contain `route` as an address type. This could work.

Comment: Yep, that's the way. I have done the same, before reading your answer :). This one helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25318167/347807

Answer (score 2):

CLGeocoder simply returns address format.
Slap this in your code and play with the contents of mapitems

```
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [MKLocalSearchRequest new];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"Pizza";
request.region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(.01, .01));
MKLocalSearch *search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc]initWithRequest:request];
[search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSArray *mapItems = response.mapItems;
    for (MKMapItem *mapItem in mapItems) {
        MKPointAnnotation *point = [MKPointAnnotation new];
        point.coordinate = mapItem.placemark.coordinate;`
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

The array returned contains `mapItems`, you can iterate over the array to pull out all the mapItems like this:

```
myMatchingItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (MKMapItem *item in response.mapItems){
                    [myMatchingItems addObject:item];
    }
```

Each `mapItem.placemark.thoroughfare` contains the Street of the location that was found.