# How to implement auto-complete for address using Apple Map Kit

Tags: ios, swift, geocoding

I want to auto-complete the address for the user as same as what google api provides in this link:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete?hl=en

How can i implement the same functionality using apple map kit?

I have tried to use the Geo Coder, i wrote this for example:

```
@IBAction func SubmitGeoCode(sender: AnyObject) {

    let address = "1 Mart"
    let coder = CLGeocoder()

    coder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        for placemark in placemarks! {

            let lines = placemark.addressDictionary?["FormattedAddressLines"] as? [String]

            for addressline in lines! {
                print(addressline)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However the results are very disappointing.

Any Apple APIs available to implement such functionality, or should i head for google api ?

Thank you

Answer (score 92, accepted):

**Update - I've created a simple example project [here](https://github.com/gm6379/MapKitAutocomplete) using Swift 3 as the original answer was written in Swift 2.**

In iOS 9.3 a new class called `MKLocalSearchCompleter` was introduced, this allows the creation of an autocomplete solution, you simply pass in the queryFragment as below:

```
var searchCompleter = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
searchCompleter.delegate = self
var searchResults = [MKLocalSearchCompletion]()

searchCompleter.queryFragment = searchField.text!
```

Then handle the results of the query using the `MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate`:

```
extension SearchViewController: MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {

    func completerDidUpdateResults(completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        searchResults = completer.results
        searchResultsTableView.reloadData()
    } 

    func completer(completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

And display the address results in an appropriate format:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let searchResult = searchResults[indexPath.row]
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    cell.textLabel?.text = searchResult.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = searchResult.subtitle
    return cell
}
```

You can then use a `MKLocalCompletion` object to instantiate a `MKLocalSearch.Request`, thus gaining access to the `MKPlacemark` and all other useful data:

```
let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request(completion: completion!)
let search = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
search.startWithCompletionHandler { (response, error) in
    if error == nil {
        let coordinate = response?.mapItems[0].placemark.coordinate
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? What result do you get?

Comment: It's awesome how this translates seamlessly to Objective C

Comment: How i can put pin on selected place??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, could you explain what you mean by a pin?

Comment: This is beautiful @GeorgeMcDonnell thanks so much. I was looking for something like this to use instead of Google Places Autocomplete API simply because some of their T&C issues. This works perfectly for my app..

Comment: Happy to help! Yeah the Google maps T&C issue is a common use case for this alternative.

Comment: Correct function signature: 
`func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter { }`
`func completer(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter, didFailWithError error: Error) { }`

Comment: Unfortunately MKLocalSearchCompleter is available in only iOS 9.3+

Comment: Any chance you can update this for Swift 5/SwiftUI?

Comment: swift5 please!!

Answer (score 17):

## Swift 5 + Combine + (Optionally) SwiftUI solution

There seem to be a number of comments on other solutions wanting a version compatible with more recent versions of Swift. Plus, It seems likely that (as I did), people will need a SwiftUI solution as well.

This builds on previous suggestions, but uses Combine to monitor the input, debounce it, and then provide results through a Publisher.

The `MapSearch` `ObservableObject` is easily used in SwiftUI (example provided), but could also be used in non-SwiftUI situations as well.

#### MapSearch ObservableObject

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import MapKit

class MapSearch : NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var locationResults : [MKLocalSearchCompletion] = []
    @Published var searchTerm = ""
    
    private var cancellables : Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    private var searchCompleter = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
    private var currentPromise : ((Result<[MKLocalSearchCompletion], Error>) -> Void)?
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        searchCompleter.delegate = self
        
        $searchTerm
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .removeDuplicates()
            .flatMap({ (currentSearchTerm) in
                self.searchTermToResults(searchTerm: currentSearchTerm)
            })
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
                //handle error
            }, receiveValue: { (results) in
                self.locationResults = results
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func searchTermToResults(searchTerm: String) -> Future<[MKLocalSearchCompletion], Error> {
        Future { promise in
            self.searchCompleter.queryFragment = searchTerm
            self.currentPromise = promise
        }
    }
}

extension MapSearch : MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {
    func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
            currentPromise?(.success(completer.results))
        }
    
    func completer(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        //could deal with the error here, but beware that it will finish the Combine publisher stream
        //currentPromise?(.failure(error))
    }
}
```

#### SwiftUI interface, including mapped locations

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var mapSearch = MapSearch()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Address", text: $mapSearch.searchTerm)
                }
                Section {
                    ForEach(mapSearch.locationResults, id: \.self) { location in
                        NavigationLink(destination: Detail(locationResult: location)) {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text(location.title)
                                Text(location.subtitle)
                                    .font(.system(.caption))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationTitle(Text("Address search"))
        }
    }
}

class DetailViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoading = true
    @Published private var coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    @Published var region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion()
    
    var coordinateForMap : CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        coordinate ?? CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    }
    
    func reconcileLocation(location: MKLocalSearchCompletion) {
        let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request(completion: location)
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
        search.start { (response, error) in
            if error == nil, let coordinate = response?.mapItems.first?.placemark.coordinate {
                self.coordinate = coordinate
                self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.03, longitudeDelta: 0.03))
                self.isLoading = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    func clear() {
        isLoading = true
    }
}

struct Detail : View {
    var locationResult : MKLocalSearchCompletion
    @StateObject private var viewModel = DetailViewModel()
    
    struct Marker: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        var location: MapMarker
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if viewModel.isLoading {
                Text("Loading...")
            } else {
                Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region,
                    annotationItems: [Marker(location: MapMarker(coordinate: viewModel.coordinateForMap))]) { (marker) in
                    marker.location
                }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            viewModel.reconcileLocation(location: locationResult)
        }.onDisappear {
            viewModel.clear()
        }
        .navigationTitle(Text(locationResult.title))
    }
}
```

Comment: NICE!!! I'm on day 50 of #100DaysOfSwiftUI and this was the perfect addition. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/checking-for-a-valid-address

Comment: This is fantastic and way better than having to pay for Google's API. However, How would you rewrite this so that if you have a few TextFields like (address, city, state, zip) you can start typing your address in the address field and then select your address and have it autocomplete the other textfields? I don't need the detail view or to display a map at all, just the autocomplete for the form. I need each TextField to bind to it's own variable (i.e. $address, $city, $state, and $zip) instead of having a searchfield that binds to mapsearch. Thanks!

Comment: @kittonian That sounds like a good project for you to take on and my answer should provide a good foundation for whatever your specific needs are. If you get stuck, you could start a question here for what the problem(s) are that you encounter.

Comment: Thanks jnpdx. I just posted my question.

Comment: Here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70571615/swiftui-using-mapkit-for-address-auto-complete

Comment: The docs for MKLocalSearchCompleter say "The completer object waits a short amount of time before initiating new searches" so the debouncing and eliminating duplicates in the Combine code should be unnecessary. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearchcompleter/1452555-queryfragment)

Comment: @jsadler Search for "MKLocalSearchCompleter rate limit" and you'll see that people do in fact run into issues. I think that debouncing is not necessarily unnecessary here.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is fully based on @George McDonnell's. I hope it helps to guys who has troubles with implementing of the last one.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableVIew: UITableView!

    //create a completer
    lazy var searchCompleter: MKLocalSearchCompleter = {
        let sC = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
        sC.delegate = self
        return sC
    }()

    var searchSource: [String]?
}

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        //change searchCompleter depends on searchBar's text
        if !searchText.isEmpty {
            searchCompleter.queryFragment = searchText
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return searchSource?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //I've created SearchCell beforehand; it might be your cell type
        let cell = self.tableVIew.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SearchCell", for: indexPath) as! SearchCell

        cell.label.text = self.searchSource?[indexPath.row]
//            + " " + searchResult.subtitle

        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {
    func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        //get result, transform it to our needs and fill our dataSource
        self.searchSource = completer.results.map { $0.title }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableVIew.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func completer(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        //handle the error
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding more context to the answer instead of just posting the code. Even context in the form of comments would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've added some context comments.

Comment: how i can add pin on selected location ??

Comment: You should handle selected location in delegate's method.

Answer (score 1):

> **SAMPLE PROJECT FOR THIS ISSUE CAN BE DOWNLOAD FROM [HERE](https://github.com/ThornTechPublic/MapKitTutorial)**

**In this sample project this issue is achieved through MKLocalSearchRequest and MapKit.**

It is showing autocomplete places just like google places API and can place the Annotation point on Apple's map (not on Google map, I hope that is only you are looking for.)

However it does not show as accurate result as you can get from Google Places API. As the problem is that Geocoding database is not obviously complete and Apple is not the company who leads this field - Google is.

**Attaching some screenshots of the sample app, so you can see if it is useful for your requirement or not.**

[image: Apple's autocomplete view.]

[image: Plotting the annotation point on Apple's map.]

> Hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: unable to use the project in swift 4..gives many error..if possible update it.

Comment: can u pls update this for swift 4 I'm in need of this exactly @Apekshit

Answer (score 1):

### **Simple Solution - SwiftUI**

**How**: searchText is linked to Textfield, when Textfield changes, searchText is queried (compared) against worldwide addresses.

The query's completion triggers completerDidUpdateResults which updates the SearchThis.swift list with those results (addresses).

**SearchThis.swift (SwiftUI)**

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct SearchThis : View {
    @StateObject var searchModel = SearchModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Type Here", text: $searchModel.searchText)
                .onChange(of: searchModel.searchText) { newValue in
                    searchModel.completer.queryFragment = searchModel.searchText
                }
            List(searchModel.locationResult, id: \.self) { results in
                Button(results.title) {print("hi")}
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SearchThis_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SearchThis()
    }
}
```

**SearchModel.swift (Class)**

```
import MapKit

class SearchModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {
    @Published var searchText = ""
    @Published var locationResult: [MKLocalSearchCompletion] = []
    
    
    let completer = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        completer.delegate = self
    }

    func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        locationResult = completer.results
    }

    func completer(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```