# Apple CLGeocoder,MKLocalSearch result differ from device map result

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, clgeocoder, mklocalsearch

In my application search with the location string, it ll return the 5 result, but that not match with default device map app.

my code 1 : CLGeocoder

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:searchKey completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (placemarks.count > 0) {
            searchLocations = placemarks;
        } else {
            searchLocations = nil;
        }
        [searchTableView reloadData];

        for (CLPlacemark *placemark in placemarks) {
            NSLog(@"place dic %@",placemark.addressDictionary);
        }
    });
}];
```

Code 2 : MKLocalSearch

```
CLLocation *userLoc = (CLLocation *)[[MYLocationManager defaultManager] currentLocation];
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLoc.coordinate, 100000, 100000);
request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchKey;
MKLocalSearch *search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSMutableArray *locs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (MKMapItem *placeM in response.mapItems) {
        [locs addObject:placeM.placemark];
    }
    if (locs.count > 0) {
        searchLocations = locs;
    } else {
        searchLocations = nil;
    }


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [searchTableView reloadData];
    });
}];
```

Both are return a same result
[image: CLGeocoder result]

Device map app result :

[image: DEvice map result]

Device map result differ from coding geo results. please help to solve this.
and my question is what type of search methodology use the default map application?
and how to get same result in coding ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380711/how-to-implement-auto-complete-for-address-using-apple-map-kit/38497997) answer. It describe all the steps needed to replicate the above result. I've tested this on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the query depends on the region you're searching in.

That's the 'Local' in `MKLocalSearch`.

The location in your code example is the user's location in a region with a side length on 10km.

The region where the built in map searches should be equal to or dependant on the region you're showing in the App at this very moment.

The region in Apples App is probably very different from the explicit region in your App.