# Obj-C - Address auto-complete/search in UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When my users fill out my app's registration form, I'm currently asking them to type their address into a UITextField. That being said, I'd love for this field to automatically complete their address (or rather, show them address options for selection as they type). Does anyone know the best way to accomplish this? I'm not sure if this is something that can be done with MapKit - I know it can be implemented in a search bar, but not necessarily in a textfield?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take a look at [`MKLocalSearchCompleter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearchcompleter). It only requires a `String` to start searching for results, so you could use it with `UITextField`; you would not have to use `UISearchBar`.

Also, here is a similar question which may be of some help:

[How to implement auto-complete for address using Apple Map Kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380711/how-to-implement-auto-complete-for-address-using-apple-map-kit)